# Formatting inner JSON value

Tags: c#, json, sql-server

I was trying to format a JSON , What i am trying to achieve is like this,

```
{
"Success": true,
"leadDetailsData": {
    "lead_title": "ISAT Auditorium",
    "client_name": "dhanil",
    "client_phone_number": "9999999999",
    "STATUS": "OPEN",
    "created_date": "15-Jan-2021",
    "created_time": "4:12PM",
    "Address": "Hormis nagar, Mookkannoor, Angamaly",
    "lead_id": 32,
    "email": "dhanil.d@g.com",
    "notes": "dhanil",
    "category": "Auditorium",
    "CreatedBy": "sins"
},
"leadAttachmentList": [],
"followupList": [{
        "FollowUp_date": "27-Jan-2021",
        "FollowUp_time": "6:00PM",
        "Followup_time_24": "18:00:00",
        "notes": "dhanil",
        "followup_id": 37,
        "STATUS": "COMPLETED",
        "FollowupResponsiblePerson": 18,
        "FollowupAction": 1,
        "Attachments": null,
        "IsCreatedByManager": null,
        "CreatedBy": "sins",
        "FollowupDate": "2021-01-27T18:00:00",
        "SelfieAttachmentID": null,
        "AudioAttachmentURL": null
    },
    {
        "FollowUp_date": "18-Mar-2021",
        "FollowUp_time": "6:00PM",
        "Followup_time_24": "18:00:00",
        "notes": "dhanil",
        "followup_id": 3047,
        "STATUS": "COMPLETED",
        "FollowupResponsiblePerson": 18,
        "FollowupAction": 1,
        "Attachments": "http://localhost:44336/Uploads/Screenshot (6).png",
        "IsCreatedByManager": false,
        "CreatedBy": "sins",
        "FollowupDate": "2021-03-18T18:00:00",
        "SelfieAttachmentID": 5034,
        "AudioAttachmentURL": [{
                "FollowupAttachmentID": 5031,
                "AudioURL": "http:\\/\\/localhost:44336\\/Uploads\\/sample1.aac"
            },
            {
                "FollowupAttachmentID": 5032,
                "AudioURL": "http:\\/\\/localhost:44336\\/Uploads\\/sample2.aac"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Here **AudioAttachmentURL** is a list inside a JSON list, but what actually i am getting is like this.

```
{
"Success": true,
"leadDetailsData": {
    "lead_title": " ISAT Auditorium",
    "client_name": "dhanil",
    "client_phone_number": "9999999999",
    "STATUS": "OPEN",
    "created_date": "15-Jan-2021",
    "created_time": "4:12PM",
    "Address": "Hormis nagar, Mookkannoor, Angamaly",
    "lead_id": 32,
    "email": "dhanil.d@g.com",
    "notes": "dhanil",
    "category": "Auditorium",
    "CreatedBy": "sins"
},
"leadAttachmentList": [],
"followupList": [
    {
        "FollowUp_date": "27-Jan-2021",
        "FollowUp_time": "6:00PM",
        "Followup_time_24": "18:00:00",
        "notes": "dhanil",
        "followup_id": 37,
        "STATUS": "COMPLETED",
        "FollowupResponsiblePerson": 18,
        "FollowupAction": 1,
        "Attachments": null,
        "IsCreatedByManager": null,
        "CreatedBy": "sins",
        "FollowupDate": "2021-01-27T18:00:00",
        "SelfieAttachmentID": null,
        "AudioAttachmentURL": null
    },
    {
        "FollowUp_date": "18-Mar-2021",
        "FollowUp_time": "6:00PM",
        "Followup_time_24": "18:00:00",
        "notes": "dhanil",
        "followup_id": 3047,
        "STATUS": "COMPLETED",
        "FollowupResponsiblePerson": 18,
        "FollowupAction": 1,
        "Attachments": "http://localhost:44336/Uploads/Screenshot (6).png",
        "IsCreatedByManager": false,
        "CreatedBy": "sins",
        "FollowupDate": "2021-03-18T18:00:00",
        "SelfieAttachmentID": 5034,
        "AudioAttachmentURL": "{\"FollowupAttachmentID\":5031,\"AudioURL\":\"http:\/\/localhost:44336\/Uploads\/sample1.aac\"},{\"FollowupAttachmentID\":5032,\"AudioURL\":\"http:\/\/localhost:44336\/Uploads\/sample2.aac\"}"
    }
]
```

}

What I am doing is I create a JSON for **AudioAttachmentURL** in SQL and return this as a dataset, and on the c# side, I create JSON.

**SQL**

```
        SELECT LeadTitle lead_title, ContactName client_name, ContactPhone client_phone_number
    , S.Name STATUS, REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), L.CreatedDate, 106), ' ', '-') created_date
    , CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), CAST(L.CreatedDate AS TIME), 0) created_time, Address [Address]
    , L.ID lead_id, ContactEmail email, AdditionalNotes notes, LC.Name category,L.CreatedBy --Added CreatedBy 21-Jan-2021
    FROM [SALE].[Lead] L
    LEFT JOIN [SALE].[Status] S ON S.ID = L.LeadStatusID
    LEFT JOIN [SALE].[LeadCategory] LC ON LC.ID = L.LeadCategoryID
    WHERE L.ID = @LeadID AND L.CompanyID = @CompanyID --AND L.ResponsiblePersonID = @EmployeeID

    --Seperated the attachment section, to get the json in described format,  dhanil 30-Dec-2020
    SELECT (LA.AttachmentURL) AS attachment_url,LA.ID AS attachmentID --added attachmentID, 27-Dec-2020,dhanil
    FROM [SALE].[LeadAttachment] LA
    INNER JOIN [SALE].[Lead] L ON l.ID = LA.LeadID 
    WHERE L.ID = @LeadID AND L.CompanyID = @CompanyID --AND L.ResponsiblePersonID = @EmployeeID

    ---22-Mar-2021 for creating json, dhanil
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMPTbl') IS NOT NULL  
    DROP TABLE #TEMPTbl

    CREATE TABLE #TEMPTbl(
    FollowupID INT,
    FollowupAttachmentID INT,
    AttachmentURL NVARCHAR(MAX),
    AudioAttachmentURL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )

    insert into #TEMPTbl 
    select f.ID FollowupID,fa.ID FollowupAttachmentID,AttachmentURL
    ,'{"FollowupAttachmentID":"","AudioURL":""}' AudioAttachmentURL 
    from [SALE].[FollowupAttachment] fa
    left join [SALE].[Followup] f on f.ID=fa.FollowupID where AttachmentURL like '%.aac%' and
    f.LeadID=@LeadID and f.CompanyID=@CompanyID
    
    update #TEMPTbl set AudioAttachmentURL=JSON_MODIFY(JSON_MODIFY(AudioAttachmentURL,'$.AudioURL',AttachmentURL),'$.FollowupAttachmentID',FollowupAttachmentID)


SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), F.FollowupDate, 106), ' ', '-') FollowUp_date, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), CAST(F.FollowupDate AS TIME), 0) FollowUp_time, CONVERT(TIME(0),F.FollowupDate) Followup_time_24 --added 24hr time format, 05-Jan-2021, dHANIL
,[AdditionalNotes] notes, F.ID followup_id, S.Name STATUS,F.UserID FollowupResponsiblePerson,F.FollowupTypeID FollowupAction
,AttachmentURL Attachments,F.IsCreatedByManager,F.CreatedBy,F.FollowupDate --20-Jan-2021, dHANIL
,SelfieAttachmentID,B.AudioAttachmentURL
FROM [SALE].[Followup] F
LEFT JOIN [SALE].[Status] S ON S.ID = F.FollowupStatusID    
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT FollowupID,MAX(AttachmentURL) AttachmentURL,ID SelfieAttachmentID FROM [SALE].FollowupAttachment WHERE AttachmentURL NOT LIKE '%.aac%' GROUP BY FollowupID,ID
)A ON A.FollowupID=F.ID
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT FollowupID,STRING_AGG(AudioAttachmentURL,',') AudioAttachmentURL FROM [#TEMPTbl] T group by FollowupID
) B ON B.FollowupID=F.ID
WHERE F.LeadID = @LeadID AND F.CompanyID = @CompanyID
ORDER BY FollowupDate
```

**C# Code**

```
           DataSet dsresult = _leadBusiness.GetFollowupDetailsData(_mapper.MapToLead(leadVM));
        JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        //object leadDetailsData = (object)json_serializer.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dsresult.Tables[0]));
        object leadAttachmentList = (object)json_serializer.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dsresult.Tables[1]));

        object followupList = (object)json_serializer.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dsresult.Tables[2]));

        //this code is for remove the [] array from the json 
        string v = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dsresult.Tables[0]);
        var leadDetailsDataStr = v.Substring(1, v.Length - 2);
        var leadDetailsData = leadDetailsDataStr!=""?JObject.Parse(leadDetailsDataStr):null;
        ////

        //var atturl = dsresult.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Attachments")).FirstOrDefault();


        string res = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            Success = true,                  
            leadDetailsData,
            leadAttachmentList,
            followupList
        });
        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(res, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };
```

Comment: To clarify this: You're not trying to _format_ the `AudioAttachmentURL` value. In the first example, it's an array of objects, but in the second it's a string property containing poorly-formatted JSON (i.e. double-serialised data).

Comment: Also, you seem to be mixing JavaScriptSerializer and JSON.NET.

Comment: @Llama the first thing is what I am trying to do, but the second is the result what i am getting

Comment: Yes, I understood that, thanks.

Comment: @Llama I'm using both JavaScriptSerializer and JSON.NET because of `leadDetailsData` i dont want a array, so to remove that array I'm using that JSON.NET

Comment: Honestly, you might be better off deserializing `followupList` as a `JArray`, and then loop through converting your `AudioAttachmentURL` to an array by adding the missing `[` and `]` around it as a string value and deserializing it.

Comment: `followupList` in the JSON is a separate 'table' in a `dataset`, So i am trying to bring the JSON from SQL side for `AudioAttachmentURL`. Is there any other way like creating the kind of result within c#

Comment: @Llama ok let me try with that

Comment: Personally, I'd be inclined to pull that data separately and then tie it together in C#. But the solution I suggested above might work as a quick fix.

Comment: @Llama Thank you, I will try with this one.

Comment: @Llama Hi I have done the looping through `JARRAy`, how can we modify the particular JSON data. I throw an error when I'm trying to modify it.

Comment: @Llama `foreach(JObject item in jArray)
                {
                    string audioURL = item.GetValue("AudioAttachmentURL").ToString();
                    if(audioURL!="")
                    {
                        audioURL = audioURL.Replace("\\", "");
                        audioURL = "[" + audioURL + "]";
                       // item.Last.Value<string>(audioURL);
                    }
                }` this is what I'm doing in looping